# What percentage of bitcoin supply sits on certain UTXO output type?

Tags: transactions, utxo-set

What percentage of bitcoin supply sits on certain UTXO output type?
Is there any dashboard that shows that? I found a dashboard displaying UTXO count but not the BTC supply per UTXO type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you, I’m only aware of a chart that shows the [partition by count](https://txstats.com/d/000000054/utxo-set-repartition-by-output-type) of the UTXO set. However, also on [txstats.com](https://txstats.com) there are individual stats per output type, which each include the amount of bitcoins held in outputs of that type.

As of 2023-08-17, these charts show:

| Output Type | Amount [₿] (mostly rounded to 100s) | % of sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [P2PKH](https://txstats.com/d/000000018) | 8'089'100 | 43.3 |
| [P2SH (includes wrapped segwit)](https://txstats.com/d/000000015) | 4'454'400 | 23.9 |
| [P2WPKH](https://txstats.com/d/000000016) | 4'267'400 | 22.9 |
| [P2PK](https://txstats.com/d/000000019) | 1'733'700 | 9.3 |
| [P2WSH](https://txstats.com/d/000000017) | 876'600 | 4.7 |
| [P2TR](https://txstats.com/d/000000055) | 35'100 | 0.2 |
| [Non-standard](https://txstats.com/d/000000013) | 2'600 | ~0.0 |
| [P2MS](https://txstats.com/d/000000005) | 57.49 | ~0.0 |
| [OP_RETURN](https://txstats.com/d/000000014) | 40.47 | ~0.0 |

---

**Update**:
Because the chart didn’t exist, I [made one](https://dune.com/murchandamus/bitcoins-utxo-set):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Murch! Anyway one could query this from own node?

Comment: I guess you could use `dumptxoutset` and then use https://github.com/theStack/utxo_dump_tools to get a more manageable format, calculate the results from there?